# Error response Content-Length mismatch "too few bytes written" when returning Content() IActionResult in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 for a web application. When I want to return a static HTML page in an error controller with `Content()` as `ActionResult`, I get an error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (268 of 270).
```

My code looks someting like this:

```cs
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
  [Route("error/500")]
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    string html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./path/to/error_page.html");
    return Content(html, "text/html");
  }
}
```

If I skip reading the static HTML file and just do this...

```cs
return Content("500 server error");
```

... then I don't get the error. Now that I'm just using built-in methods, shouldn't the ASP.NET Core framework handle the `Content-Length`? Does anyone know what causes this and how to prevent the error?

Edit: I also tried the following with the Index() method, yet same result:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
  string html = "";
  using (StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText("./path/to/error_page.html"))
  {
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  return Content(html, "text/html");
}
```

Comment: Do you have other code running in the application that tries to set the content length?

Comment: Yes, probably. Either runtime minification or something else (which doesn't give other errors, by the way). Regardless, I managed to find a solution by adjusting the static HTML files. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out that the code isn't the problem, but the formatting of the static HTML file. Can you spot the difference?

Before:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Ooops!</h1>
  <p>Something went wrong. Please try again later...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

After:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Ooops!</h1>
  <p>Something went wrong. Please try again later...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The difference is the missing empty line end and the space at the end of the self-closed `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` tag. Two characters and exactly the missing two bytes in "too few bytes written (268 of 270)". Maybe the issue is caused by a conflict elsewhere in my middleware – I don't know – but it's solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write the stream instead to the response.

It will return stream which loads the contents of the file to the response and content length should be correct.

```
    [Route("error/500")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string filePath = "./path/to/error_page.html";
        using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/html");
        }
    }
```

Another approach is to set content-length by yourself by adding following line to your code:

```
Response.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(html);
```

Comment: Correction suggestions: `FileStream` type instead of `StreamReader` in line 5 and `reader` instead of `stream` in line 7.

Comment: The approach with FileStreamResult might work, but there might be an undesired side-effect. The intention of the error controller is to keep the status code 500 in the result, and as I recall, FileStreamResult will alter that status code to 200 for OK or similar. Or maybe I'm wrong about this?

Comment: @JakobBagterp ... thanks I updated the answer. You can still set response status code like this: `Response.StatusCode = 500;`